# How to make a playa field required in a safecracker form?

Tags: add-on, safecracker, playa

How do I make a Playa select field required in my Safecracker rules?

I have a playa field in my safecracker form as follows. The field generally works fine, but I cannot get Safecracker to require it. I've tried rules:training_teams="required".

```
<select id="training_teams" name="training_teams[selections][]">
    <option value="">Select Race</option>
    {embed="includes/_training_teams" selected="{training_teams:child_ids}"}
</select>
```

The embed file is as follows:

```
{exp:channel:entries dynamic="no" status="open" channel="rally_athlete_program" 
    orderby="title" sort="asc" date_field="event_date"
date_field_start="{current_time format='%Y-%m-%d'} 12:01 AM"}
    <option value="{entry_id}">{if entry_id == embed:selected}selected{/if}{title}</option>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: have you tried setting the field itself to required in the fieldtype settings?

Comment: Stacey, could you answer below so this question goes off the unanswered list? Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Playa has respected EE’s “Is this a required field?” field setting since version 4.0.5. Simply set that setting to “Yes” and save your field.